# The 'Apple Developer Program License Agreement' has been updated

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, xcode9

My Xcode automatically updated now I'm getting this error:

> The 'Apple Developer Program License Agreement' has been updated. In
>   order to access certain membership resources, you must accept the
>   latest license agreement.

I feel so dumb. Where do I go to accept this?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Login to your Apple developer account and accept updated license agreement:

https://developer.apple.com/account

[image]

**Note**: Popup blocker can block this notification popup window. (Ensure your web browser's pop blocker is not enabled, if this notification is not visible to you)

Comment: Does anybody know where can I find the changes of each version?

Comment: The adblocker was the problem for me

Comment: what happened if i forgot to In order to access certain membership resources,  must accept the latest license agreement by

Comment: Hi, I only see an expiration banner, I have not renewed my membership yet. I hope I will be able to accept after I pay for the next year. ATM I am not able to accept new terms in the account section.

Answer (score 5):

I had to log into Apple Store Connect, access "Agreements, Tax and Banking", accept and fill a new agreement.

That just happened to me .. but it didn't show the toast notification with "Accept" when accessing Apple Developer.

Answer (score 1):

You should go to the Apple Developer Center…

https://developer.apple.com/account

Comment: That works. You'd think there would be a way to accept it in Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

I had to open the explorer console and i realize that there was another popup blocked bellow the current one, so i apply display:none to see it and accept the agreement.